# Scrapy certificate_transparency error

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm triying to use scrapy on Windows 10. There is no problem in installation, but when I use scrapy command on cmd there is always the following error

```
C:\Users\Isaias HL\Desktop\noticias\noticias\spiders\spider_cbr.py:6: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider, Rule
2018-02-16 15:11:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: 
noticias)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in 
<module>
sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", 
line 149, in execute
cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", 
line 252, in __init__
log_scrapy_info(self.settings)
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", 
line 149, in log_scrapy_info
for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 35, in scrapy_components_versions
("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 43, in _get_openssl_version
import OpenSSL
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", 
line 8, in <module>
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", 
line 12, in <module>
from cryptography import x509
File "C:\Users\Isaias HL\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
```

Comment: may no longer be relevant but I believe twisted had problems with py3 on windows at one point not long ago. so you were forced to use py2.7 for scrapy on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Installing https://pypi.org/project/ctutlz/ fixed the issue for me.

`pip install ctutlz`